# Shortening the Hex number by removing leading zeros in Java

Tags: java, hex

I have Hex number available in string and I want to shorten it by removing leading zeros. I need to do it in Java

For example :

```
0000000000000000000000000A000000   -> 0x0A000000
0x0000000000000000000000000A000000 -> 0x0A000000

000000000000000000000000C0A80000   -> 0xC0A80000
0x000000000000000000000000C0A80000 -> 0xC0A80000
```

Currently below code throws NumberFormatException exception

```
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong("0x0000000000000000000000000A000000")));
```

Comment: Looks like his does.

Comment: @Lino prefixing hex numbers with `0x` is common in many programming languages (including Java)

Comment: @GyroGearless literals are prefixed (`int i = 0xABC;`), but not strings AFAIK (`Long.toHexString(0x11) -> 11`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `Long.parseLong` correctly.

It should be:

```
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong("0000000000000000000000000A000000",16)));
```

but that will result with

```
a000000
```

which is not exactly what you wanted.

You'll have to add some additional formatting to get the exact output you wanted:

```
String shortHex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong("0000000000000000000000000A000000",16)).toUpperCase ();
String formatted = (shortHex.length () % 2 == 0 ? "0x":"0x0") + shortHex;
System.out.println (formatted);
```

Now the output will be:

```
0x0A000000
```

If your input starts with "0x", you'll have to trim that prefix before calling `parseLong`.

Comment: Depending on the value of the hex string, it might be preferable to use new BigInteger(hex, 16).toString(16) instead of Long.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, hex strings don't start with 0x, this is merely a prefix for [hexadecimal literals](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Hexadecimalintegerliteral.htm).

One possibility to achieve what you want, would be the following:

```
void foo(String myString) {
    /*
        Here we're making myString upper case and checking if it begins w/ 0x.
        If the string starts with 0X, that'll be replaced with an empty string.
    */
    if ((myString = myString.ToUpperCase()).startsWith("0X")) {
        myString = myString.replace("0X", "");
    }

    String parsedHex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(myString, 16 /* This is the radix (base) of the number. In this case we want hex (16) */));
    System.out.println(String.format("0x%s%s", parsedHex.length() % 2 == 0 ? "" : "0" /* If it's an odd number, add a leading zero. */, parsedHex));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea:

1. Check overflow
2. only pick last 8 characters from the original long string, e.g. `0A000000` from `0000000000000000000000000A000000`.
3. add "0x" prefix.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment on the OP, hex strings (as seen by `Long.parseLong()`)don't start with `0x`. That's why you are getting a NumberFormatException.

There are multiple ways of getting around this.

1. Remove the `0x` if neccesary, parse, then add it back

   ```
   static String shortenHex(String input){
       if(input.charAt(1)=='x') inputnput = input.substring(2);
       return "0x"+Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(shortenedInput, 16)).toUpperCase();
   }
   ```
2. Add the `0x` if applicable, then use a regex

   ```
   static String  shortenHex(String input){
       if(input.charAt(1)!= 'x') input = "0x"+input;
       return input.replaceAll("(?<=0x)0+","");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string form and not the literal form, then this should work.

```java
      String[] hex = {
            "0000000000000000000000000A000000",
            "0x0000000000000000000000000A000000",
            "000000000000000000000000C0A80000",
            "0x000000000000000000000000C0A80000"
      };

      for (String h : hex) {
         String hmod = h.replaceAll("[0x]*([123456789ABCDEF].*)", "0x$1");
         System.out.println(h + " -> " + hmod);
      }
```